# simple question on python's split

Tags: python, string, split

Not sure why last print is off? Please see comments for specific question

```
 john = ['john doe', 44, 32000]

jane = ['jane doe', 23, 12000]

people = [john, jane]

for p in people: 
    #===========================================================================
    # p[0] prints "john doe" as expected
    # p[0].split() prints ['john', 'doe'] as expected
    # p[0].split()[0] prints "john" and "jane" as expected
    #===========================================================================
    for x in p[0].split():
        print('--> ', x[0]) 

    # prints "j","d" - not sure why
    # expected "john" and "jane"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. p[0].split() returns a list of strings
2. for x in... deals with each string in the list
3. x[0] is therefore the first character in the string

you probably want to get rid of the subscript after 'x'.

Comment: OMG, what a newb i am. Thank you. Don't know how i could have missed that

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this

```
for p in people: 
    #===========================================================================
    # p[0] prints "john doe" as expected
    # p[0].split() prints ['john', 'doe'] as expected
    # p[0].split()[0] prints "john" and "jane" as expected
    #===========================================================================
    for x in p.split():
        print('--> ', x)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, p[0].split() gives you ['john', 'doe'].  In your loop, x refers in turn to the elements of this list, "john" and "doe".  x[0] refers to the first item in either of these-- the first character in the string.